# Exclude a certain match in a capturing group in regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a regex capturing group and I want to exclude a number if it matches a certain pattern also.

This is my capturing group:

https://regex101.com/r/zL1tL8/1

if \n is followed by a number and character like "**1st**", "**2nd**", "**4dffgsd**", "**3sf**" then it should stop the match **BEFORE** the number.

0-9 is important in the capturing group.

So far I have this pattern `[0-9][a-zA-Z]+` to match a number followed by characters. How do I apply this to the capturing group as a condition?

Update:

https://regex101.com/r/zL1tL8/4

Line 1 is wrong.

It should not match a number followed by characters

Comment: Can you post the text of the regex instead of a link to it.

Comment: It's unclear if `\n` is a newline (0x0a) or a literal \ plus `n`. It's also nclear what you are trying to match.

Comment: Hi, i edited the sample regex already. what i really want is to un match if there's a number followed by characters \n1st should not match 1st. but it should match \n$300 or \n599

Comment: Did you look at my answer below? It should do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to use a **negative lookahead** to "stop" the match if something after matches your pattern. So, something like this might work:

```
(\\n(?![0-9][a-zA-Z]))
```

See it in use here: https://regex101.com/r/zL1tL8/2

Here's a page with some more info on lookahead and lookbehind: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html

Comment: It is assumed that the OP knows then how to then capture everything after "\n", but for completeness's sake, `^\\n(?![0-9][A-Z])(.+)$` contains a capturing group that captures everything after the "\n" (as "i" was used in linked example, I omitted the "a-z" from the character class). "^" and "$" anchors are necessary given "m" modifier.